# MSBUILD Target - Custom Coded Task causing Visual Studio build to complete but "fail"

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm creating a Nuget Package that will run some functions before the main project build. In my case I am updating a value in the .csproj file.  I have create a custom dll which I've packaged into a Nuget package **foo** which has a custom class called OnBuild which overrides and implements a **Execute** method

```
public class OnBuild : Task
{
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        Console.Write("Package running...");
        try
        {
            Executor runner = new Executor();
            runner.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error running the package");
            return false;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("Run complete");
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Executor class reads the projects's CSPROJ file, and added a property to a property group if required and saves the file.

So far so good.  I have wired this up via a custom Target and all is well. So here comes the question.

If I now add my Nuget package **foo** to my project **bar** and start a build from the command line

```
dotnet build bar.csproj
```

It works perfectly. The build succeeds and my CSPROJ has its new property value.

However, if I open **bar** from Visual Studio, and execute a build, I see the build completes (all the build artefacts are created and put in the correct bin folder, however VS complains that the **"Build failed.  See the build log for details"**. However there is no detail.  Nothing has gone wrong.

I am totally confused! Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've had similar problems in the past with different versions of VS - Which versions do you have installed?

Comment: Maybe you can increase Visual Studio's log level so that you get more detailed output?

Comment: @DaiBok I'm running VS on the Mac.

Comment: @mu88 I've upped it to the max and spent ages reading the output.  Nothing looks to have failed.  I do wonder if because I am updating the .csproj file VS is spotting that and trying to reload it before the "build" process has finished

Comment: I think dotnet build is not the same as msbuild which I think VS uses , try figure out which build engine you are using in VS and see if it is different from the dotnet build engine. Also seeing the content of your bar.csproj might help